# How to let gcc actually allocate variables instead substituting with symbols?

Tags: gcc, memory, optimization, gdb

I noticed that if I have variables defined as `char a = 'a';` or `char a; a = 'a';` or even `char a; a = 'a'; a = 'b';`, and I try to do `print a` in gdb, it tells me `No symbol "a" in current context.`. Apparently gcc, during compilation, optimizes a to be a character constant, instead of a `char` variable holding a certain value.

How do I tell gcc not to do this trick, but really treat `a` as a variable (allocate memory and assign the character value to its memory)?

Comment: What's the point?  If you're only using the constant value, you don't need to know; if you're making use of it as a 'real' variable, GCC won't optimize it away.  Did you try compiling without any optimization (no `-O` option, or `-O0`)?

Comment: It's more for academic purposes. I want to examine the binary content as the program executes. But apparently because of the above issues, I can't even print variables b/c they are sub'ed by constants.

Comment: So, make the code modify the variable more often, or more obscurely.

Comment: Possibly try to qualify the variable as `volatile`.